# Food consumption for transparent human body to make feel less odd?

Tags: biology, food

[image]

What food transparent humans consume so that others can't see what they have eaten, like what all consumable food is transparent like water.

like how people find it embarrassing when people point out what they eat after seeing what is stuck in their teeth...People might laugh seeing their transparent stomach and laugh at what they ate. So there is a requirement for transparent food.

Or how to make transparent food any chemicals can we create transparent food.

Comment: I am not sure I can understand what you are asking. Can you proofread it?

Comment: @L.Dutch the English is not perfect, but I think the idea is carried out unambiguously. OP has transparent creatures (invisible man style), and he is worried that the undigested content of their stomach will awkwarldy show up since the food itself is not transparent. He is asking how to solve that issue (his solution of choice being transparent food). I don't really see how the question could be read in another way

Comment: @BarbaudJulien, read the version before the current edit, when I left the comment

Comment: @L.Dutch oh, I see. (I actually don't know how to do that but I get your point)

Comment: I wonder if those transparent men have transparent sh*t. If they don't, it'll be a LOT more awkward to see that accumulating in one's intestines than seeing their undigested food. Hum.

Comment: Just puree or liquify everything?

Comment: Nice example of a transparent meal in your picture. I'm not so sure about looking down at a belly and seeing those eyes looking back at me, maybe cut off the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Of course you have transparent food**

Your question is “what transparent food can transparent humans consume”. The answer is “whatever food you want”. It’s your world. You decided there would be transparent humans. If you want to decide there is transparent food, I don’t see how that would be a problem to anyone. The hard leap of faith is to believe in a fully transparent body (complete with transparent bones, transparent blood, etc, etc). If you’re comfortable making your reader accept that, there’s really no problem in telling him that some pigs are transparent too.

**If you feel the need to “justify” the existence of transparent food**

Again, you don’t need to. You can just say it exists. But if you think it needs to be justified, nothing more straightforward, since you already consider having transparent humans. If we assume your humans have naturally evolved to be transparent, then there is a whole evolutionary branch of mammals that is gradually more and more transparent, all the way up to transparent humans. You have plenty of transparent cattle, because somehow developing a fully transparent body is a huge evolutionary leap that took millions of years. It didn’t suddenly appear; it went along with the other changes that led to the emergence of homo sapiens.

Even if for some reasons, your transparent people just became transparent at the snap of a finger, scientists will have definitely studied the bio-mechanisms that allow their bodies to be transparent. From there, they have been able to mimic this property and produce transparent GMOs for your people to eat.

**You don’t need transparent food**

You could have other mechanisms to avoid showing the content of your guts. For example, if evolution led to animals becoming transparent, it would make sense that they also evolved other traits to help them *actually* be transparent. As such, those animals have a much faster digestion system; in the wild, they hide to eat and digest everything in about 10 minutes and poop out the rest. Once they are done, they can come out of hiding and comfortably be transparent again. Your humans would just have to eat their tacos in private and wait 10 minutes before they are socially acceptable again.

**Clothes?**

Humans have already come up with a strategy to cover parts of their bodies they don't want everybody to see. Clothing. Just don't go to your restaurant naked (transparent is not invisible by the way, so if showing your genitalia is still awkward in your world, you're gonna need pants.  And invisible or not, it's kind of awkward to rub your genitalia on the same chair as everyone else, no?)

Comment: /it's kind of awkward/   I will try it and let you know!

Answer (score 3):

Embarrassment is when someone in a society is doing very different than others.

**No embarrassment when it becomes normal**

When everybody is doing what others are doing, it becomes normal e.g. becoming naked on a street is embarrassing but it is normal on a nude beach.

**Do you laugh at food in someones plate?**

When everybody can see what is stuck in others' teeth or inside the stomach, then nobody will laugh. It will be just like everybody can see what food is in others' plate in a restaurant.

**Smoothie**

Everyone wears clothes so everything below the neck is covered. Only mouth and neck are problems. So

- turn your food into smoothie
- consume it with a straw
- drink water to clear mouth and neck

**Raw meat of transparent animals**

In a world where humans are transparent, there would also exist transparent animals. One can eat raw meat dishes as told [here](https://www.bonappetit.com/trends/article/15-raw-meat-dishes-from-around-the-world) and [here](https://www.tasteatlas.com/most-popular-raw-meat-dishes-in-the-world). If the refractive index of transparent fluid in the stomach and of raw meat are equal, then raw meat will be almost invisible in the stomach because there would be no reflection at the interface.

Comment: Good point. Tho in a society where transparent humans are a minority and not the norm, they might still be uncomfortable having their insides exposed. Also, even the norm doesn't come free of embarrassment. Everybody has genitalia but getting your pants pulled down in public is still embarrassing. So are farts, snort, etc... It's still conceivable that broadcasting your digestive process live could be awkward, depending on the arbitrary social standards that are up to the OP

Comment: @BarbaudJulien "getting your pants pulled down in public is still embarrassing. So are farts, snort, etc." So everyone hides the genitalia and holds farts as long as possible. So if "broadcasting your digestive process live" becomes very embarrassing, people will find a way to hide it. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, that is my point; there is no guarantee that normalizing would make the awkwardness go away (it's pretty much up to OP to decide). Which circles back to the original question: what's a good way to avoid showing what you have eaten?

Comment: @BarbaudJulien I edited again

Answer (score 2):

If they want totally transparent food then the only answer is cannibalism and eating other transparent humans, that should do the trick.

If that's a bit too gruesome then the next best thing would be camouflage instead of transparency. They could liquidise their food and mix it with a strong food dye. Their digestive organs would then be shown in uniform colour. If they wanted to show off they could even use a different coloured dye at each meal :o)

Comment: Why is it the only answer?

Comment: I don't think that all of the required nutrients for a human can be made colourless. As an example riboflavin is a yellow-orange colour.

Comment: That is a good point. But if we have admitted the existence of transparent humans, I think we have to admit that all their components are... The argument would essentially prevent the existence of transparent humans. I believe we have to work on the assumption that all of their components are transparent. Otherwise, if humans are transparent and riboflavin can't be, it means they don't contain riboflavin, so cannibalism won't bring you that anyway, right?

Comment: I think the real problem is defining when visible matter becomes invisible. Riboflavin exists in the world outside of humans is then eaten, absorbed and becomes part of the body. In fact everything that constitutes a human being once started as part of the environment. So there should be some boundary where visible matter becomes invisible when going in and invisible matter becomes visible on the way out.

Answer (score 2):

**Distilled spirits**

Ethanol has considerable caloric value.  It is possible to meet ones caloric needs using ethanol alone.  Ethanol is clear and would not be seen in the stomachs of these clear people.  The clear people also seem easily embarrassed and likely would be embarrassed by the visibility of their vivid green bile, brown stool forming and moving about in the bowel like little stool animals (which they call stoolimals), and bladders full of yellow urine.  Ethanol might help calm those anxieties although since they live on ethanol they would be accustomed to it, and it would take a fair bit.

Of course ethanol calories are "empty" calories and so your clear people would fortify their gin with vitamins and minerals much as breakfast cereal is fortified.  Amino acids to meet protein requirements would also be added to the distilled spirits.

Comment: It had to be gin, didn't it....somehow, in a world where all you consume is alcohol, it seems like a natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Their unique metabolism allows them to survive on pure methanol. It contains lots of calories and, when digested, turns into carbon dioxide and water.

They can eat other food but, even if it was transparent initially after digestion it turns into you-know-what. Which is in most cases not transparent. Society is ok seeing it. Or it is terribly indecent and transparents cover it up.

You are talking about transparent people, not invisible. The creature in your picture has very visible eyes and some internal organs. If transparent people were shy about their physiology they would wear clothes just like people do.

Comment: You don't need food only for calories. You need proteins and a whole load of other nutrients to provide matter to your body. A living organism has different requirements than a car engine. They can't survive on oure methanol, and if they still have to eat normal food, I don't see how it solves the problem.

Comment: @Barbaud Julien - I explicitly said "allows them to survive" and "they can eat other food" so I am not sure what point you are trying to make.

Comment: I am pointing out that methanol *does not* allow a living organism to survive. It brings in energy (calories) but not matter (proteins, etc). You need matter to grow and maintain your size. Your reaction produces CO2, which you would have to *spend energy* to assimilate (which is what plants do), which would consume all the calories you got from producing CO2 in the first place (you would just be going circles). You can't get both energy and matter from your methanol, so you can't survive on it.

Comment: @Barbaud Julien - one more time then. Drink a bottle of methanol in the morning, go out all transparent and decent. Return home by evening and eat "other food" with all the nutriens you so concerned about. Get to sleep, in the morning get rid of indecent processed non-transparent "other food", drink another bottle and go out. You pointing out contradiction that doesn't exist.

Comment: In your last comment, the methanol solution you are proposing still requires you to eat normal food. It therefore doesn't solve the issue. Instead you are proposing another solution (eating at night). The methanol doesn't really bring anything to the table in that case. Shifting your eating schedule to eat in private does make for a better answer imo

Comment: @Barbaud Julien "methanol doesn't really bring anything to the table in that case" - it brings calories that can be consumed any time without looking weird, exactly as the question requires. "Shifting your eating schedule to eat in private does make for a better answer" - fasting 99% of you awake time is a better answer then getting calories any time you want? Well, I don't see how to continue this discussion then. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sugary water is an easier way to do the job if all you are concerned about is getting calories in. I just think the big leap of having a methanol drinking species is unnecessary, and that the bulk of your answer to the question hinges, not on the methanol, but on the eating schedule (which is a good idea, but would need to rework the answer to make it appear, as it currently isn't mentioned)